# Changing hair cards on the fly

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, hair, procedural

So what I'm trying to make is a procedural hair card geo nodes setup that generates cards for a hair curves system.

I was able to make it work so that it generates the card meshes, places the UVs properly on the atlas and allows me to cycle through the different hair cards on the existing atlas.

The problem I am having is that when I change the hair card number it replaces it on all of the hair curves.

What I have been struggling with is making it so that I can choose a hair card number, add a few cards (curves), then change to a different hair card and add those but the ones I previously placed keep the old hair card.

Basically my question is, is that even possible or am I just wasting my time?

If it is could someone please suggest how I could approach this?